# Changing grouping for bookmarks of appendix

Tags: hyperref, appendices

I have an appendix with multiple chapters, while I like it that the main chapters of the document appear on the highest hierarchy level in the bookmarks, I would like the appendix chaptes to be children of the appendix bookmark. It would be even better if i could prefix the chapter number

I have this for the bookmarks

```
Appendices
Additional Images
Additional Code
```

and would like this

```
Appendices
|-A Additional Images
|-B Additional Code
```

MNWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Additional Images}
    blah
    \chapter{Additional Code}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With package `bookmark`, the level of the next bookmark entry can be changed via `\bookmarksetupnext`. In this case, the level of the appendix bookmark should behave as `\part` (numeric value -1):

```
\bookmarksetupnext{level=part}
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{...}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{open,numbered}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section A}
\chapter{Summary}
\bookmarksetupnext{level=part}
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Additional Images}
    blah
    \chapter{Additional Code}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: nice highquality awnser. Explanation, example and screenshot.

Comment: `bookmarksopenlevel=0` behaves oddly with this, for all chapters before the appendix it shows them collapsed, however the `Appendices` bookmark is open. While I like this behaviour, could explain it/ how to change it?

Comment: @ted: `Appendices` is a *part* entry. If you want to have the bookmarks collapsed, just use the default or `\bookmarksetup{open=false}` or `\bookmarksetup{openlevel=-1}`.

Comment: When I click on for instance an appendix content like `A Additional images` in your answer, It goes to cover page instead. Is there any further option needed here?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent All bookmarks are going to the correct page in my example, compiled with `pdflatex` or `dvips`/`ps2pdf`. How do you compile the example? Are the packages up-to-date?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I solved my problem by adding `\appendix` after `\begin{appendices}` with aid of `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}`

Comment: I have a bibliography chapter after the appendix, but it gets collapsed below the appendix. Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: @Overdrivr Add `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` before the bibliography.